# Faster way to write binary file with Python/Cython

Tags: python, struct, cython, binaryfiles, mmap

I checked 2 ways to read a binary file using Python/Cython:

The first one was using mmap and struct.unpack module:

```
import mmap

import os
import struct

fd = os.open(filePath, os.O_RDONLY)
mmap_file = mmap.mmap(fd, length=24, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ, offset=0)
Xmin = struct.unpack("i", mmap_file[:4])[0]
Xmax = Xmin + struct.unpack("i", mmap_file[12:16])[0]
Ymax = struct.unpack("i", mmap_file[4:8])[0]
Ymin = Ymax - struct.unpack("i", mmap_file[16:20])[0]
Zmax = struct.unpack("1f", mmap_file[8:12])[0]
```

The second one was using mmap and from_buffer:

```
class StructHeaderLID(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('Xmin', c_int),('Ymax', c_int),('Zmax', c_float),('tileX', c_int),('tileY', c_int)]

    d_array = StructHeaderLID*1

    fd = os.open(filePath, os.O_RDWR)
    mmap_file = mmap.mmap(fd, length=24, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE, offset=0)
    data = d_array.from_buffer(mmap_file)
    for i in data:
        Xmin = i.Xmin
        Xmax = Xmin + i.tileX
        Ymax = i.Ymax
        Ymin = Ymax - i.tileY
        Zmax = i.Zmax
```

and I found out that the second one was faster.

The issue I want to solve is the fastest way to write a new binary file. I know how to write it with struct.pack:

```
f = open(filePath, 'wb')
line = struct.pack("i", 500000)+struct.pack("i", 4000000)
f.write(line)
f.close()
```

but I would like to know if there is a faster way (or something similar to mmap + from_buffer but for writing).

Thank you.

Pablo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among the fastest ways will be to use NumPy.  Create an array and write it directly to the file, or use their `memmap()` function.

Comment: What I did so far was to write a NumPy array, and when its length was bigger than 1000 items I wrote it directly to file (using pickle.dump).The problem with memmap() function is that I have to set a shape and my array shape is variable, therefore I just can use memmap() when all the items have been added to the array and I know its shape, but not using memmap() when the length of the array is bigger than 1000. Am I right?

Comment: Don't use pickle to write a NumPy array to a file!  Use `np.save()` or `np.memmap()` or one of the many other functions in NumPy which directly write it.  If you don't know how many elements in advance, just allocate the largest number you expect in an array, then at the end write only the part you need, e.g. `np.save('filename.npy', array[:10000]`.